# Take photos with Dolphin 99EX on Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK(ARMV4I)

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

My problem is the next:

I have an application developed for Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK(ARMV4I) which is running on Honeywell Dolphin 99EX.

Basically I am using the API from Honeywell to take pictures: CameraAPI.h.

The problem is at the photo camera initialization.

In the working project every time when I call camInit function it returns RESULT_ERR_NOTCONNECTED.

If I am creating a test project and try same thing it is working.

From what I saw in debug console at camInit calling:

1. The test project which is working loads:

Load module: quartz.dll.0409.MUI

Load module: MMTimer.dll

Load module: quartz.dll

Load module: msdmo.dll

Load module: wmvdmoe.dll

Load module: icm.dll

Load module: msrle32.dll

Unload module: msrle32.dll

Unload module: icm.dll

Load module: DDRAW.dll

and after that camInit returns 0.

2. The working project which is not working loads:

Load module: quartz.dll.0409.MUI

Load module: MMTimer.dll

Load module: quartz.dll

and after that camInit returns RESULT_ERR_NOTCONNECTED.

It loads only the first 3 dlls from a normal workflow.

Do you know why the working project stops to load the rest of the dlls?

Or do you know an approach to fix the problem?

Thanks

Horea

Answer (score 0):

On the 99EX, the camera and the decoder use the same hardware bus and cannot both be initialized and connected at the same time.  Before calling camInit(), call decDisconnect() (c++) or DecodeAssembly.Disconnect() (c#).